# Jenkins and Github Enterprise 2.17 failing Pull Request builds only

Tags: github, jenkins

My company just upgraded out GHE instance to 2.17 and I am having a hell of a time with Jenkins now. Up until the upgrade everything worked, but now whenever a pull request is built, I get the following error:

```
19:17:43 Connecting to https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/v3 using cxxxxxxxxxxxxxn/****** (Credentials to access the xxxxxxxxxxx openstack api)

GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result

com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:591)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1902)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:757)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3005)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:629)
Caused: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: Server returned HTTP response code: 200, message: 'OK' for URL: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/v3/users/AT
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:646)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:607)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:285)
    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:247)
    at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getUser(GitHub.java:398)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitHubSCMFileSystem.java:304)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:293)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:103)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:293)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am by no means a Jenkins expert, but this is really puzzling me. Jobs off the master branch run fine, jobs based on a tag run fine. It is only jobs off of a PR that break. Also, how does a response code of 200 lead to an error?

I tried adding a logger to see if I could get the raw output from the web call but I had no luck getting the right level so I could actually see it if it is outputted.

I have tried google and no luck, it gets drowned out by the library exception. I have also been trying to look up issues with GHE and I have yet to find anything. I am hoping that someone can point me in the direction on how I can get the raw output from the webcall as I think that will point me in the direction I need to go to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a change in the handling of names in 2.17 to support organizations being allowed to have spaces in their name. Essentially "AT" != "at" where pre 2.17 they were treated as the same.

Updating the organization in the organization folder configuration allowed me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

With the hint in the above comment, we fixed our build pipeline. We did it in Jenkins by changing a character in the Repository URL from lowercase to an uppercase. It sounds very odd but it works, and without it, it breaks again. Probably a bug in the last update.

In your pipeline go to **configure**. Under **Branch Sources**, change one of the characters to uppercase.

Repository HTTPS URL https://git.yourenterprisedomain.com/**C**hange/intoUppercase

Comment: I ran into the same issue with GHE 2.21.x, and resolved it the same way, thank you. It's just weird.